# If $a|b$, then why the gcd of $a$ and $b$ is $a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

If $a$ divides $b$, then why is $(a,b)=a?$

I am trying to justify this for myself and this is what I have done.     I was wondering if it is correct?

**Claim:** Let $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$. If $a|b$ then $(a,b)=a$.

**Justification:** Since $a|b$, there must exist an integer $m$ such that $b=am$. Now

$$
\begin{align}
(a,b)&=(a,am)\\
&=a(1,m)\\
&=a\times 1\\
&=a
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The step $(a,am) = a(1,m)$ is not incorrect, but an explanation for it is longer than an alternate explanation for the problem itself, which is given in the answer below.

Comment: @Ofcourseit'snotme You are wrong.

Comment: @Ofcourseit'snotme $(42,3)=3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\mid b$ then, since $a\mid a$, $a$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. And obviously no natural number greater than $a$ divides $a$. So, $a$ is the *greatest* common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That was too easy.

Comment: @Vafa As I say again and again to my students: if you want a more complex proof, I can provide one, but I prefer this one.

Comment: No, that is perfectly fine. Actually, my lecturer also said something quite similar but I did not get it at the time but now I understand it perfectly. I understand that my justification is needlessly complicated but is it incorrect?

Comment: @Vafa Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer when the system allows me to.

Comment: Is common divider (instead of common divisor) a common term? That's the first time I heard it and I am just asking because I am curious.

Comment: @Levent That has already been edited by someone else. Sorry about that. Please take into account the fact that English isn't even my second language.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos oh it is also not my first language so I just wondered if it is a common term or not :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For all natural numbers $a>0$, $a|a$ (because $a \div a =1$)

For all natural numbers $a>0$ and $b>0$, $a|b$ implies that $b$ is divisible by $a$ and $b\ge a$.

With $b \ge a$, $a$ is divisible by $b$ if and only if $a=b$.

Because of that, $a$ is divisible by $a$ and $b$ is also divisible by $a$, but $a$ can't be divisible by any number larger than itself, implies $(a,b)=a.$

Answer (score 0):

due to the uniqueness of prime decomposition, the division structure  $(\mathbb{N^+,|)}$ is isomorphic to the natural lattice structure on the free abelian monoid $M = (\oplus_{j \in \omega}\mathbb{N}_j,+)$ induced by the identical linear orderings on each component $\mathbb{N}_j \cong (\mathbb{N},<)$.

if $a=2^{n_0}3^{n_1}\dots$ (where only a finite number of the $n_j$ are non-zero), then the sublattice $a\mathbb{N^+}$ corresponds to the sublattice 
$M_a=(\oplus_{j \in \omega}(\mathbb{N}_j+n_j),+)$.

this correspondence makes it easy to see that, (now viewing the lattice  as a category, with the obvious morphisms) then the *translation* **f**$_a$: $M \to M_a$ is a faithful functor between $M$ and its full subcategory $M_a$, and **f**$_a$ is naturally equivalent to **id**$_M$